# expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not pisaContext

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to send PDF via email:

```
def render_to_pdf(template_src, context_dict={}):
    template = get_template(template_src)
    html = template.render(context_dict)
    result = BytesIO()
    pdf = pisa.pisaDocument(BytesIO(html.encode("ISO-8859-1")), result)
    if not pdf.err:
        return pdf
    return None
```

in my **views**:

```
pdf = render_to_pdf('expenses/pdf_report.html', data)
mail.attach_file(pdf)
mail.send()
```

I get this error:

> expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not pisaContext

How can I get str or bytes instead of `pisaContext`?

Comment: You have to return result in your render_to_pdf(): `return HttpResponse(result.getvalue(), content_type='application/pdf')`.

Comment: @Borut expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not HttpResponse

Comment: Based on Django documentation: [link](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/email/), you should use attach() instead of attach_file(). It should work with return result.getvalue() then.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try below code. not tested but it should work

```
from django.template.loader import render_to_string

def render_to_pdf(template_src, context_dict={}):
    html = render_to_string(template_src, context_dict)
    result = BytesIO()
    pdf = pisa.pisaDocument(BytesIO(html.encode("ISO-8859-1")), result)
    if not pdf.err:
        return result.getvalue()
    return None
```

Reference: https://github.com/codingforentrepreneurs/Guides/blob/master/all/Render_to_PDF_in_Django.md